# print removing regex failing

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a nifty script we all need to remove all print statements from python files in a directory/or a single python file before we do code roll. I have printremover.py:

```
def read_content_to_linelist(the_file):
    try:
        f = file(the_file, 'r')
        content = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return content
    except IOError:
        return 0

def remove_print(linelist):
    string = ""
    for line in linelist:
        if re.match(r"^\s*print.*", line):
            linelist.remove(line)
        else:
    for line in linelist:
        string += line
    return string
```

I am playing with a file fake.py while I test it:

```
name = 'cody'

print name
print 'cody'
print 4
```

when I print the list from `read_content_to_linelist`, I get good data. But when I remove_print, I get everything right except it leaves `print 'cody'` for some reason. It does leave the variable, and remove the other 2 prints.

Comment: what about prints in functions?

Comment: Also. it is giving me `['#!/user/bin/env python\n', '# coding: utf-8\n', "name = 'cody'\n", '\n', 'print name\n', "print 'cody'\n", 'print 4']` but when I print out the line by line in the for loop, it skips "print 'cody\n" each time, counting to 6 when there were 7 lines. I check the lines within remove_print immediately before the for loop

Comment: I mean if you have prints in classes, functions etc.. are you removing them too?

Comment: yes sir, I am only checking for white space at the beginning. in my fake file, I have no functions or classes however- and an odd error, of skipping the 6 of 7 line

Comment: Note this will also remove such things as `printers = [ ... ]`, because `printers` matches the RE `print.*`. All in all, this sounds like a potentially disastrous idea. Better to convert all those `print` statements to something like `if (debug) print ...`. Or wrap them in a class that can either be a custom logger or a no-op, depending on a flag or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `remove_print`, the first loop should be:

```
for line in linelist[:]:
    ...
```

This creates a copy of `linelist`, which is necessary if it's being modified inside the loop.

Also, your `else` can (should) be left out, since nothing happens in it.

Another note, your regular expression doesn't need the leading caret (^) since `re.match` checks from the beginning of the string; you'd only need the caret with `re.search`.

Comment: you answer had the easier changes and simplest to understand, thank you all. I see now

Comment: This is inefficient. You are creating a copy of a list just to avoid the bug, but the code doesn't require modification of the list in the first place. You are concatenating the good lines in `string`. The list is not used, so deleting the bad lines is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `re.sub` instead. When you `remove` from `list` then the ordering gets changed. In the `for` loop

1. first element gets removed.
2. second element comes in place of first,third on second.
3. `for` loop counter is on second ,but the element has changed.

Directly use

```
print re.sub(r"^\s*print.*$","",x,flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

where `x` is `f.read()`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are modifying the list as you loop over it. Your logic can be greatly simplified using the built in `filter` and `join` functions:

```
def read_content_to_linelist(the_file):
    try:
        f = file(the_file, 'r')
        content = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return content
    except IOError:
        return 0

def good_line(line):
    return not re.match(r"\s*print.*", line)

def remove_print(linelist):
    good_lines = filter(good_line, linelist)
    return ''.join(good_lines)
```

Comment: What didn't work about it? It worked for me. I did `lines = read_content_to_linelist("fake.py")` then `print remove_print(lines)` and I got just the `name = 'cody'` line and a blank line.

Comment: I got error deeper in my code. Let me check again Jake

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [unparser.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/parser/unparse.py)  with the ast module to remove the prints:

```
import inspect
import importlib
import ast
from unparser import Unparser # unparser.py

class RemovePrint(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
    def visit_Print(self, node):
        self.count += 1
        print("Removed {} print/s".format(self.count))
        self.generic_visit(node)
    return None




mod = "yourfile"
mod = importlib.import_module(mod)
p = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mod))

t = RemovePrint().visit(p)
print(ast.dump(p))
Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='name', ctx=Store())], `value=Str(s='cody')), FunctionDef(name='foo', args=arguments(args=[Name(id='x', ctx=Param())], vararg=None, kwarg=None, defaults=[]), body=[AugAssign(target=Name(id='x', ctx=Store()), op=Add(), value=Num(n=4)), Return(value=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()))], decorator_list=[]), ClassDef(name='Foo', bases=[], body=[FunctionDef(name='__init__', args=arguments(args=[Name(id='self', ctx=Param())], vararg=None, kwarg=None, defaults=[]), body=[Assign(targets=[Attribute(value=Name(id='self', ctx=Load()), attr='foo', ctx=Store())], value=Str(s='foo'))], decorator_list=[])], decorator_list=[])]`)


Unparser(p, open("temp_test.py", "w"))
```

Needs a bit of work but outputs:

```
name = 'cody'

def foo(x):
    x += 4
    return x

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'foo'
'
```

From:

```
name = 'cody
print name
print 'cody'
print 4


def foo(x):
    x += 4
    print x
    return x


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "foo"
        print("foo")
```

This won't work using python3 and only tested  using python2.7, i will add the python3 code when I get it working.